# Battery warning (?) No words, just an image:

Tags: battery, huawei

Yesterday, I connected my Huawei u 9805 smartphone to a reliable USB charger when it was at 11, 12, or 13 % (I don't remember, but I have occasionally waited much longer - it warns at about 7 %, I think).

This morning, only the following Image apperas on the screen: (I cannot photograph it now)

[image: approximate error (?) screen]

The phone won't start; this image is displayed when I connect the charger Instead of the usual "battery loading" screen. There is not text on the screen, making this hard to Google. And I don't think its meaning is clear. Battery defect?? Can't they just put these letters onto the screen? Actually it looks like it's loading, doesn't it?

The Phone is about 13 months old; 4 months ago the same thing happened and I just replaced the battery without thinking about it. (I still retained the original.) Usually the battery lasts at least 2 days (I only activate Wifi in the evening at home, I don't use mobile data or multimedia); I wouldn't expect it to break this early or this suddenly.

**What does this error screen mean?** Is it an error screen in the first place??

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the screen that displays when the charger is plugged in.  I don't have a Huwaie device, but I do see a similar full-screen battery icon when my device is plugged in (but turned off).

I don't think this is an error message, try a different charger if you are having issues (that is probably your issue, not your device).